# How to set php.ini path

Tags: php, mysql

I installed xampp to work on php projects, and I'm sure I installed it the same as in the course, but when I try to run a Development Server by running `php -S localhost:8080`, it replies with

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-crash-course-2020\14_product_crud\02_better\public\products\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php-crash-course-2020\14_product_crud\02_better\public\products\index.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-crash-course-2020\14_product_crud\02_better\public\products\index.php on line 3

I have done a lot of research and I think the problem is that there is no path to php.ini.
In php.ini I uncommented the extension `pdo_mysql` but that didn't work, so on the command line, I typed `php --ini` and it replied with

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:    
Loaded Configuration File: (none)   
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)   
Additional .ini files parsed: (none)
```

I have found the php.ini file in `C:/xampp/php/php.ini` which from my research should be the right place, so I think I need to set a path for xampp to find php.ini, but I can't find how.
Is there a command to set a path for php.ini?

Comment: Maybe you just need to set PHP path in environment variables. Please check this if you are on Windows :  
https://dinocajic.medium.com/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce

Comment: *"I think I need to set a path for xampp to find php.ini, but I can't find how. Is there a command to set a path for php.ini?"* Not sure if it helps but  you can do something like `<VirtualHost ip>
[...]
PHPINIDir path_of_your_php_ini...
[...]
</VirtualHost>` when you create virtual hosts in apache 2